# RSpec/Mongoid: Expect to change count on embedded models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have two Mongoid models: User and EmailAccounts. The latter is embedded in the User model. That configuration should be fine because it works generally.
Now I'm trying to write an integration test for my user edit form that looks like this:

```
describe 'Add EmailAccount' do
  it 'Adds an email account', js: true do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_without_email_accounts)
    visit edit_user_path(user)
    expect{
      click_link 'New Email Account'
      within '.nested-fields' do
        fill_in 'Account Name', with: 'New Email Account'
        fill_in 'Other Field', with: 'Other Data'
      end
      click_button 'Save'
    }.to change(EmailAccount, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Because EmailAccount is an embedded model the change of count is always 0.
Can I check for a change of the EmailAccount counter in any similar way? Or do I have to go a different way?
This won't work neither:

```
      }.to change(user.email_accounts, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: sorry just out of context couldn't hold the curiosity, whats you name again :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and managed to solve it by using a combination the answers posted here.

```
expect {
  #action 
}.to change { foo.reload.bars.count }.by(1)
```

Comment: Hi Arjan. That did the trick, thanks! But it should be ```}.to change``` (without the underscore).

Comment: My code was `}.to change(foo.reload.bars, :count).by(1)` and it didn't work. Anyway changing to `}.to change{foo.reload.bars.count}.by(1)` works like a charm. Still not sure about the difference between using `(.., :count)` and `{...count}`. Thanks Arjan anyway.

Comment: @Phil `change(object, :method)` seems to cache object, then call the `:method` twice. So, `foo.reload.bars` seems to be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Edited with new answer:

I've been able to use this syntax in my spec of a Mongoid document:

```
expect {
  #action
}.to change { Model.count }.by(1)
```

Note that the count statement is within brackets and doesn't use a :count parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. But it still does not work with embedded mongodb documents.

Comment: I updated my answer after having to do the same in my own test

Comment: Hi Eric. Does that really work for embedded models? Because even when I do EmailAccount.count in the console I get 0. Which is what I expect.

Comment: I forgot this was specific to an embedded model.  I printed "Model" to represent what you are really counting, so you would put expect {
  #action
}.to change { user.email_accounts.count }.by(1)

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
user.reload
}.to change(user.email_accounts, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still does not work. I have similar examples in an ActiveRecord project, where it's no problem doing stuff like that. But not with embedded documents in mongoid. I did a workaround and check the resultig respond object for generated table rows.