# Table count does not increase after save returns true for nested resource rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a 'Mastertag' model as a nested resource for 'Project' with a create action as:

```
def create
    @mastertag =  @project.mastertags.build(params[:mastertag])

    if @mastertag.save
         redirect_to project_mastertags_path, notice: 'Mastertag was successfully created.' 
      else
         render action: "new" 
    end
end
```

where @project is initialized in a before filter method.

I have an rspec test as:

```
describe "POST create" do

   context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Mastertag" do

        expect {
          post :create, { project_id: @project.id, mastertag: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:mastertag_without_project) }
        }.to change(Mastertag, :count).by(1)
   end
end
```

When I run the test, the @mastertag.save method returns true however the count still remains the same. The test hence fails. This looks pretty strange. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was using Mongoid and 'Mastertags' was embedded into Project, there is no separate collection for Mastertags.

I had to change the code to :

```
describe "POST create" do

    context "with valid params" do
          it "creates a new Mastertag" do

            expect {
              post :create, { project_id: @project.id, mastertag: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:mastertag_without_project) }
            }.to change {@project.reload.mastertags.count}.by(1)
    end
end
```

I got help from this Stackoverflow question : [RSpec/Mongoid: Expect to change count on embedded models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839322/rspec-mongoid-expect-to-change-count-on-embedded-models)

Answer (score 0):

Check your **project_mastertags_path** and make sure the redirect after **if @mastertag.save** works.

also, try replacing `if @mastertag.save` with `if @project.save` in your create method.

Comment: @Myth17, and the result appears in DB?

Comment: Inserted a puts statement to check.

Comment: I noticed you havn't defined @project in your create method, yet.

Comment: The @project gets defined in a before filter method.

Comment: try replacing `if @mastertag.save` with `if @project.save` in your create method.

Comment: Dosent help. Still the same issue.

Comment: This code successfully creates a new MasterTag when I test in development mode. SO has to be some other issue. :/

Comment: I found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550721/testing-post-create-with-rspec) that might be helpful.

Comment: does not seem to be helping. :(

Comment: @Myth17, if you play a bit and put `raise` or something into `if @mastertag.save..end` block. Will the exception be raised (or whatever happen) if you run a test?

Comment: Yup. If I put a "puts" statement inside the if @mastertag.save..end block. It gets executed.